# What does it mean when a Linear equation has no solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Take for example the linear equation $$-7x+3=-7x+2$$

What I understand by this is that there is no number that would make the Left hand side and the right hand side of the equation equal.But if so, shouldn't there NOT be an "=" sign between the two expressions, because they cannot be equivalent to each other if they don't have a solution?

Shouldn't it also be understood this way?:

If the equation is simplified, we'd get: $3=2$
which is not true. Hence,

$$-7x+3 \neq -7x+2$$

I'm confused.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: The solution set to a system of equations is the set of all values such that each of the equations are true.  In your example, the solution set of $-7x+3=-7x+2$ is empty, i.e. there are no solutions.  Or, as you have noticed, this could be rephrased as the solution set of $3=2$ is empty.  Now... it is perfectly acceptable to have $3=2$ as a statement.  We are well aware of the fact that $3=2$ is false.  Statements may be true or false.  We are interested in whether certain values of variables make certain statements true or false.  In this specific case the answer is obviously none.

Comment: @JMoravitz Superb explanation.

Comment: If you prefer to think of it this way, think of each equation in your system of equations as a question.  Maybe replace each equals sign with $=?$ or if you are a programmer with `==`.  We are looking for the values such that plugging in those values we get an answer of 'Yes' or rather an answer of 'True' for each.

Comment: In two variables you may accept it more easily. We have two linear equations, say, $2x+3y=1$ and $4x+6y=-1$. But this system has no solution, if not $3=0$ (which may happen, e.g., in $\Bbb F_3$).

Answer (score 2):

An equation, even such as $2=3$, is a mathematical expression that has a truth value. This one is $\text{false}$.

When there is an unknown, the expression can be conditionally true: $3x-9=0$ is $\text{true}$ if and only if $x=3$ is $\text{true}$.

$3x-9=3x$ is never $\text{true}$, and this is said to be an *impossible* equation.

Answer (score 1):

Once it has been agreed among the humans of interest that the string $-7x+3=-7x+2$ is an *equation* in $x$, it is no longer to be interpreted as the statement (a):

> (a) The right-hand side results from the left-hand side by means of algebraic manipulations.

But rather as part of the problem (b):

> (b) Find the values of $x$ such that the identity holds.

And the algebraic manipulations are among lines which, ideally, should be linked by the connective of ligical equivalence $\Leftrightarrow$ (ore, more visually, $\Updownarrow$). Said link means "the values of $x$ such that the equation above holds are exactly the values of $x$ such that the equation below holds".

Sometimes, lines may be linked by connectives such as $\Downarrow$, which means "the values of $x$ that solve the equation above also solve the equation below". This, albeit useful when one wants to prove that an equation has no solutions, typically needs a subsequent check of which solutions of the latter, less restrictive equation are actually solutions of the former.

Of course, lines containing equations are allowed to be connected by explanatory text.

It is certiainly true that, since the equation $-7x+3=-7x+2$ has no solutions, then the *in*equation $-7x+3\ne -7x+2$ is solved by all $x$ (and it is therefore a full-fledged in*equality*, just like an equation solved by all $x$ is often called *identity* or *equality*).